# how to use a formatted string in the role of function arguments

Tags: php, function, arguments

how to use a formatted string in the role of function arguments? Or insert arguments through the cycle?
I do not know how much will I have arguments.

I use

```
function get_fie($type, $id) {
    if($type == 'product') {
        echo "Product: {$id}";
    }
}
$product_id = 11;
$str = array('function' => 'get_fie', 'arg' => sprintf("'product', %d", $product_id));
$str['function']($str['arg']);
```

Answer (score 1):

further, you could serialize them into a single variable in your initial array and unserialize them in your functions. But I think passing the array is your best bet...

Comment: What if it is not my function, for example, I get it from a plugin?

Comment: another option is passing an object. I would guess a well-designed plugin would use object-passing. (One designed for simplicity would use array passing). Otherwise, you might need to add your own wrapper function to split out the variables and pass it to the appropriate function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

http://www.php.net/func_get_args

To pass as many args as you want. Or pass them as an array and call them by index.